# Tex Live 'Back end gone'

Tags: pdftex, packages

I can open the tlshell gui fine, but when I try to load the remote packages, I get this error:[image]

When I click ok, it just closes the whole program. I'm on Windows 10 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX). And I have installed packages with this before.

Comment: texlive 2021 has been released and so texlive2020 is gone. You should connect to an history repository if you still need packages for texlive 2020.

Comment: How do I do that? Or is there some way of updating without a fresh install?

Comment: you can set the historic repo with `tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2020/tlnet-final`. I don't know if upgrading works, I always do a fresh install.

Comment: I installed texlive 2021 ut still got this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## For Windows

Open terminal and type

```bash
tlmgr update --self --all
```

It may tell you to follow the instructions in https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html. This page is for Linux Systems so you don't need to follow all the instructions in this page. Just take a look at (8)

> 8. Download the latest [update-tlmgr-latest.sh](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh) and run it like this:
>
>    `sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade`
>
>    (The extra options are to try to prevent the upgrade from happening unintentionally.)

But normally you cannot run a `.sh` file in Windows Systems. So the trick is: you can do a little change on the download link:

```
# this is for Linux
https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
# this is for Windows
https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe
```

Put the second link in your browser or simply click [here](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.exe), then your browser would start to download `update-tlmgr-latest.exe`. Double click it once it is downloaded to your computer. Just follow the instructions and complete the update.

Last step: open TeX Live Manager -- All done!

Comment: This fixed one problem and I was able to download package repository info, but when I tried to install a new package, the "backend gone" error occurred again. Went ahead and manually installed texlive2023, and that fixed it
.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted item of texlive old version in PATH then it worked.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default repository used by the utility is a mirror located at https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet.

Try to change the it: Go to Options->Repositories... and choose a repository from some country.