# Change from TL-2019 to TL-2020

Tags: installing, texlive-2019, texlive-2020

I have TL-2019 and TL-2020 both installed on my PC (Win 11). My problem is that I'm compiling my LaTeX files with TL-2019 and not with TL-2020. Please how can I remove TL-2019 and switch to TL-2020 in order to update to TL-2023?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which `tex` you are calling depends on the `PATH` environment variable - are you able to put (as text) the output of running the command `echo %PATH%` in your question?

Comment: in the windows search type "environment variables", this should give you a dialog where you can change the path variable and e.g. move the one to tl2020 up front.

Comment: Or this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644824/244233 , which shows how to change the path.

Comment: It's ok @enkorvaks tank you so much.